# How to extract all lat-long coordinates from DirectionsResult object (Google Maps Javascript directions API)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

In the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) it is said that :

> The `DirectionsResult` contains the result of the directions query,
>   which you may either handle yourself, or pass to a DirectionsRenderer
>   object, which can automatically handle displaying the result on a map

I don't want the directions to be displayed on the map,using DirectionsRenderer object,but I need to  access the lat-long coordinates from DirectionsResult object beforehand.

Is there any way in which I can do this ?

Comment: The documentation also says that *It is prohibited to use Google Maps Directions API data without displaying a Google map.*

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, a `DirectionsResult` contains `routes` property which is an array of `DirectionRoute` objects. Each route has `legs` which contain coordinates. You should be able to iterate through the properties to access the lat longs of each leg.

```
/**
 * Assuming you have a directions result
 * assigned to const myDirectionsResult
 */

// es6 syntax

// const myDirectionsResult = ...

const legCoordinates = [];

myDirectionsResult.routes.forEach(route => {
  route.legs.forEach(leg => {
    const {start_location, end_location} = leg;

    legCoordinates.push({ start_location, end_location });
  });
});
```